# How can I get filtered query string in MS SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I'm using MS SQL Server 2008 EXPRESS R2 built-in full-text search feature `CONTAINS()`. I know that it filters query string and doesn't search for words like `and, or` also I noticed that it filters special characters like `/, \`. When I'm displaying search results I want to highlight matched words so I need filtered query that was used for search and not the original one. Is it possible?

Comment: This is an application-level problem, not a database-level one. It is the responsiblity of the application that executes the search to highlight the words, so effectively you'll need to parse the result and insert the appropriate encoding to highlight the word in your application.

Comment: Yes, I'm responsible for the highlight but DBMS decides which parts to filter and I want to know how it makes its decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at [`sys.dm_fts_parser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280463.aspx)

```
SELECT display_term
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser (' "know that it filters query string and doesn''t search 
                        for words  like and, or also I noticed that it filters
                        special characters like /, \" ', 1033, 0, 0)    
WHERE special_term='Exact Match'
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. I also used `sys.dm_fts_parser (' FORMSOF( FREETEXT, "know ... /, \") ', 1033, 0, 0 )` to have full list.